# Spring Saml Force IDP Reauthentication when Assertion Age Expires

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml, service-provider

We have a Spring SAML SP service set up that allows our customers to use SAML to login to our applications. Our Spring SAML app has a max assertion age configured as 12 hours and users have their assertion ages expired often. Currently when they try to login with a session older then the max assertion they get an error. They then have to logout of their IDP, then login and try again.

They are able to get around expired sessions by setting a max assertion age in the configuration of our SP on the IDP side to something less then our 12 hours max. Then their IDP correctly prompts for reauth. I'd like to force reauth when their assertion is expired from our SP side. Is there a way to do that? I know using SAMLEntry point you can force auth all of the time, but we want to only reauth when we need them to.

Answer (score 0):

this statement:

> Currently when they try to login with a session older then the max
> assertion they get an error. They then have to logout of their IDP,
> then login and try again.

indicates that there's a problem on the IdP side (that is, they are killing their sessions early, or something similar), not yours. If you send a user with a standard SP-init AuthnRequest, the IdP should honor it. If the user has to log out of their IdP, that's the IdP's issue to resolve, not yours.

If you're **not** using the standard SP-init/AuthnRequest mechanism, then you need to update your question, and explain **exactly** your process.